# Event Calender for aspx webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

Im attempting at building an aspx website and would like an event calendar for one of the pages. Site visitors should only have read only access but I want admin to be able to edit the events as they arise.

Can anyone suggest a calendar plugin which may be of use?

Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with the calendar built into ASP.NET?

Comment: I could, but im unsure of how to achieve the read/write permissions that I'm looking for without having the control itself on a members only page(which is no good)

Comment: Why not use the day render event to add a link to an editor if the user has the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Check out also the updated [DHTMLX Scheduler .NET](http://scheduler-net.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd part extensions:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/dbschedulerprovider/defaultcs.aspx
or use DevExpress ASP.NET Tools or else

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use the Google calendar API which works a treat. can be modified by simply logging into my google account. I can also delegate access to the calendar so that others may update the calendar when necessary.

heres the tutorial i followed from codeproject
[CodeProject - Using Google calendar in an ASP NET website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201907/Using-Google-Calendar-in-an-ASP-NET-Website)